# How to prevent transactions replay in solana?

Tags: solana-program, token, swap, raydium

Suppose I want to buy a token. If I send 100 transactions to buy it within 1 minute, how can I ensure that only at most 1 of these 100 transactions will be successful?

Answer (score 2):

When you send a transaction, it first gets verified and then written to the shared ledger. All the validators compare incoming transactions (represented as a hash so they dont have to compare all the instructions, accounts, etc) and if they spot a duplicate they discard it.
If you send multiple times the same transaction, only the first one to be processed will succeed and the others will fail.

Comment: Thanx for reply, but please allow me to make my question more specific, suppose I dont know when this token start trading, and all I want to do is landing my tx on the first block, so I keep sending transaction before this token start trading, so how can I ensure that only at most 1 of these 100 transactions will be successful?

Comment: as of today and my (restricted) knowledge there is no way to ensure that one of your transaction will be successfully landing in the first block / any block you wish

Comment: Thanx, I found solution

Comment: whats the solution you found if i may ask?

Comment: I check ATA during each transaction, If ATA exists, that means one of my tx has been landed on chain successfully